# Query with subquery-count and groupby

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the ERD

[image]

I want to count number of gender ('Male' and 'Female') for each month irrespective of year.

What I have tried so far is that I can count number of males and females for each month separately like below

**Query**

```
Select u.Gender, datename(month, p.EntryDate) month, COUNT(p.User_Id) count 
    from [HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Patients] p,[HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Users] u 
    where u.Id = p.User_Id 
    group by datename(month, p.EntryDate), u.Gender
```

**Result**

[image]

I want it like below

**Expected Result**

```
Month    | MaleCount | FemaleCount
June     |     0     |      2
November |     1     |      1
```

To achieve above I try following query

**Query**

```
Select datename(month, p.EntryDate) month, 
        (select count(u.gender) from [HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Users] u
        where u.Id = p.User_Id and u.Gender = 'Female'
        group by u.Gender) female,
        (select count(u.gender) from [HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Users] u
        where u.Id = p.User_Id and u.Gender = 'Male'
        group by u.Gender) male
    from [HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Patients] p
    group by datename(month, p.EntryDate)
```

**Error**

```
Column 'HospitalManagement.dbo.Patients.User_Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Below are the create statements of tables (I am using **MSSql**)

```
-- Creating table 'Users'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Password] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [UserName] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Age] bigint  NULL,
    [Gender] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [NRIC] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Comments] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Address] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [ContactNo] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [FullName] nvarchar(max)  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Patients'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patients] (
    [Id] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Disease] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Occupation] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [EntryDate] datetime  NULL,
    [EntryTime] time  NULL,
    [User_Id] bigint  NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Comment: mysql or sql server??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Sql Server.

Comment: female count in june month will be 1 but result we are getting 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you are directly using User_Id column in select clause which is not present in the GROUP BY.

You can change the correlated subqueries to faster LEFT JOINs (assuming the User_Id is unique in the Patients table).

```
select
    datename(month, p.EntryDate) mon,
    count(case when u.Gender = 'Female' then 1 end) female_cnt,
    count(case when u.Gender = 'Male' then 1 end) male_cnt
from [Patients] p left join [Users] u
on p.User_Id = u.Id
group by datename(month, p.EntryDate);
```

#### EDIT:

you can use a lookup CTE to generate all months and then do LEFT JOIN with it like this:

```
;WITH months(mn, mon) AS
(
    SELECT 1, DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(month,0,GETDATE())) mon
    UNION ALL
    SELECT mn+1, DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,mn,GETDATE()))
    FROM months
    WHERE mn < 12
)
select
    m.mon mon,
    count(case when u.Gender = 'Female' then 1 end) female_cnt,
    count(case when u.Gender = 'Male' then 1 end) male_cnt
from months m left join [Patients] p 
on m.mon = datename(month, p.EntryDate)
left join [Users] u
on p.User_Id = u.Id
group by m.mon;
```

Comment: This one works. Can you please tell me that How can I get say `Month=January, Male=0, Female=0` | `Month=February, Male=0, Female=0` | `Month=April, Male=0, Female=0` ... and so on ... Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
 Select 
    datename(month, p.EntryDate) month,
    COUNT(IF(u.Gender = 'Male', 1, NULL) AS MaleCount,  
    COUNT(IF(u.Gender = 'Female', 1, NULL) AS FemaleCount
from 
    [HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Patients] p,[HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Users] u 
where 
    u.Id = p.User_Id 
group by 
    datename(month, p.EntryDate)
```

Comment: it is more faster then case when statement

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do in MySQL or Oracle. Have not tried in MSSQL though. But as these are standard SQL function (and is available in MSSQL), this should work in MSSQL as well.

```
Select  datename(month, p.EntryDate) month , SUM(CASE WHEN u.Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0) MaleCount, SUM(CASE WHEN u.Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0) FemaleCount,  
    from [HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Patients] p,[HospitalManagement].[dbo].[Users] u 
    where u.Id = p.User_Id 
    group by datename(month, p.EntryDate)
```

Typically I am adding 1 in case of the specific gender to get the result.

Note: If there are any syntax errors please let me know with the error, I can correct it.